# php how to publish data filtered by the current_user

Tags: php, wordpress

What is the best way to make the data available to not signed in users but at the same time keep the set up of an individual user who created it.

I have a site where you can create a table of data. Everything is filtered by $current_user->ID. When the user complete his table, I would like to create the option to publish his table of data. How can I do that if all is filtered by the $current_user->ID? So if you aren't signed it you will not get any data because the Select query won't by able to compare it to anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$_GET` element to display `user_id`